# Missing Temporal in Coruna

Tags: qgis

I was following a tutorial on time series which showed a screen grab of the properties dialogue with "Temporal" as a tab.  When I folowed the tutorial using the same file Temporal is missing.  Do I need to do anyhing to activate Temporal?  I have reloaded Qgis but still no Temporal.

Answer (score 4):

Temporal controller is available from version 3.14 onwards, 3.10 does not have it. Please use TimeManager Plugin instead: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/